# Compatibility layer above AWS & GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

Has anyone developed an abstraction layer above [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) and the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)? It would be nice to be able to develop a system that could be migrated between either of those two platforms. I am interested in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) or [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).  Both projects provide an App Engine like environment.  I have successfully ran Python applications, with no modifications, built using [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) on TyphoonAE.

You can also look at [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) or [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) for frameworks with features designed to make moving between GAE + bigtable and other datastores easy.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about an infrastructure service (IaaS - ec2) and platform service (PaaS - GAE) - the latter is built on something like the former (but obviously GAE doesn't run on ec2).

To get the portability you want - you would need to build in something that runs nicely on GAE - and then work out how to rebuild that platform infrastructure underneath on EC2 (probably not a trivial task). Given that GAE for python is very close to django, for simple apps, carefully written, you may be able to achieve this somewhat by using some django images on AWS/ec2 (obviously a sys admin burden now rests with you whereas it did not with GAE).

Hope that helps !